# Unable to access couchbase web console for AWS EC2 RHEL server

Tags: web, amazon-web-services, console, couchbase

I have just installed couchbase  3.0.1 on Amazon Web Services EC2 free RHEL instance (3.10.0-123.8.1.el7.x86_64). The installation was successful and I the couchbase is running on this server.
To access couchbase web console from web browser I need to to use the syntaax http://:8091
unfortunately this is not working. I tried using Public DNS and Public IP both.
For example:

On Google Chrome browser --> http://ec2-54-69-221-173.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8091

I have also installed the couchbase outside the AWS on VMPlayer. That works fine.

Please let me know is there any additional step I need to take care in case of AWS instance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the instance security group configured to allow incoming traffic on port 8091 from your browser IP?

Answer (score 1):

I would start troubleshooting this in two ways:

1) Confirm there a couchbase process running on port 8091 on that node using netstat.

2) Make sure you have your security groups for this node set up to allow access to port 8091. If not, add a rule to the security group.

If I had to guess, it is going to be #2 though.

Comment: Kirk,  Yes #2 worked. I added the new rule  all traffic and was able to connect to web console. Thanks!